# Changing a bit within a byte in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

So I understand how to change an individual bit within a byte, what I am not sure is why my particular code is not working.

```
public static void setBit(byte[] input, int position, int value) {
    int byteLocation = position / 8;
    int bitLocation = position % 8;
    byte tempByte = input[byteLocation];

    if (value == 0) 
    tempByte = (byte) (tempByte & ~(1 << bitLocation));
    else
    tempByte = (byte) (tempByte | (1 << bitLocation));

    input[byteLocation] = tempByte;
}
```

Now I have been testing it with the string "Testing1" which is 64bits long, then attempting to set the bits and display the value. It works a treat up to 46 bits, then on the 47th bit if I attempt to set it to 1 it borks up, works fine with 0 however.

Can't see the error in my ways, here's how I am testing it

```
String test = "Testing1";

byte[] bytes = test.getBytes();

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    System.out.print(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i])).replace(' ', '0') + "[" + i + "] ");

setBit(bytes, 44, 1);
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    System.out.print(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i])).replace(' ', '0') + "[" + i + "] ");
```

The following is the output when I attempt to change the 47th bit to a 1

```
01010100[0] 01100101[1] 01110011[2] 01110100[3] 01101001[4] 01101110[5] 01100111[6] 00110001[7] 
01010100[0] 01100101[1] 01110011[2] 01110100[3] 01101001[4] 11111111111111111111111111101110[5] 01100111[6] 00110001[7]
```

Comment: what does your setBit() method do?

Comment: Forgot method headers my bad, edited them in now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change formatting as

```
Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & bytes[i])
```

byte needs to be masked off because it is sign-extended, not zero-extended, to 32-bit int

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are setting the sign bit in the byte in question.  So, that byte now has a negative value.  You call `Integer.toBinaryString()`, which takes an int as it's argument, not a byte.  The byte get promoted to an int, and it correctly evaluates the value of:

```
11101110
```

to it's equivalent integer:

```
11111111111111111111111111101110
```

Answer (score 0):

I made your method smaller using `^` (xor)

```
public static void setBit(byte[] input, int position, int value) {
    int byteLocation = position / 8;
    int bitLocation = position % 8;
    input[byteLocation] = (byte) (input[byteLocation] ^ (byte) (1 << bitLocation));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at it in too much detail but I think the problem with the one bite is that it's being extended to an int (Since it's signed, the 1 extends to a negative int).

Just take the last 8 characters of the string and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ive recently had to do something like this. 
I managed to achieve it through (a lot of use of the whiteboard but..) shifting the original bits right by the position of the LSB I wanted to replace and making all bits inclusive of the MSB I wanted to replace, 1's.
I then AND'ed the bits I want in place of the bits I want to replace, shifted left the same number I shifted right, OR'ing the result with the original and AND'ed by an XOR'ed mask of the replacement. (Take a breath, I'll try to explain)

Let's say I have the bytes:
1111 **1010** 0001 1001
and I want to replace the nibble 1010 with 0001 to produce:
1111 **0001** 0001 1001.
The operation I went through to achieve this is:
1) Shift right by 8 to produce:
 
**0000 0000 1111 1010** 
2) OR a mask of 0xf (1111) to produce:
 
**0000 0000 1111 1111**
3) AND the replacement of 0001 with 0000 0000 1111 1111 to produce:
**0000 0000 0000 0001**
4) Shift left by 8 to produce: 
**0000 0001 0000 0000**
5) Shift the mask by the LSB position and XOR with full bytes
**1111 1111 1111 1111**
**0000 1111 0000 0000**
 ==================
**1111 0000 1111 1111**
6) AND the XOR'ed, shifted mask with the original to produce:
**1111 0000 0001 1001**
**1111 0000 1111 1111**
 ==================
**1111 0000 0001 1001**
7) OR that result of the above with the replacement:
**1111 0000 0001 1001

0000 0001 0000 0000

 ==================

1111 0001 0001 1001 << *end result*

 ==================**





In java, this results in the function:

```
public long overwriteBits(long overwrite, long with, long shift, long mask)
{
    return ((((overwrite >> shift) | mask) & with) << shift) | (overwrite & (~0 ^ (mask << shift)));
}
```

Where "overwrite" is the original data, "with" are the bits you want in place of the bits in position "shift" and mask is a a series of positive bits with the same length of the replacement.

To do the above I'd call (in sudo):
overwriteBits(1111**1010**00011001, **0001**, 8, 1111)

I want to mention that the above will work for replacing bits in any primitive, no need for byte arrays. e.g. Replacing 11 bits, as below:
1101001010101101 **1111 0101 101** 001101
with **1010 1010 101**
overwriteBits(1101001010101101 **1111 0101 101** 001101**,** **1010 1010 101,** 6**,** 11111111111)
1101001010101101 **1111 0101 101** 001101
1101001010101101 **1010 1010 101** 001101

overwriteBits(1789785421l, 1365l, 6, 0x7FF)